# Using 'in' keyword to match substrings from a list is not working as intended

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looping through a list of substrings to match to another list of the parent strings. This works flawlessly in another script, but for whatever reason I can't get it to return a match. It returns "Mismatch" every. single. time. And I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

It won't match given the code (at the bottom), but yet I can use:

```
    print('ACC-'+a[0] == 'ACC-123')
    output: True
```

I know the 'in' keyword is supposed to be fine when using substrings, but this is directly contradicting that. I am not sure If I am missing something or if I just understood the 'in' keyword wrong. This is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
    a = ['123','456','789']
    b = ['23523','ACC-123','283923978']

    for row in a:
        if row in b:
            print(f'Match: {row}')
    else:
        print(f'Mismatch: {row}')
```

It should return a match on the a[0] element.

Comment: `123` isn’t in `b`. It is in `b[1]` though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example doesn't work because string '123' doesn't exists in list `b` (only "ACC-123"). You should iterate every value in list `b` and check for substring:

```
a = ['123','456','789']
b = ['23523','ACC-123','283923978']

for row in a:
    if any(row in b_val for b_val in b):
        print(f'Match: {row}')
    else:
        print(f'Mismatch: {row}')
```

Prints:

```
Match: 123
Mismatch: 456
Mismatch: 789
```

Comment: I was not familiar with the any() function, but this worked like a charm. Thank you!